# Error Message on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

Hey all, this is my first post. I recently upgraded a wordpress site, all things load but on the top of the page and bottom of the page I get this error.

**Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_6v2kul3t823ah9074g3cl2lrt6, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/admin_m3/incommunion.org/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-automatic-upgrade/wordpress-automatic-upgrade.php on line 121**

How can I remove it from the page? I believe the server automatically upgraded the version of Wordpress.

Its running on Apache, PHP5 Fast CGI

Any idea?

Newbie A

Comment: Please add some info about what kind of environment your blog runs on. From the look of it, anyway, it sounds like a server issue (hard disk full or missing rights to write to `/tmp`) that should be sorted out by the administrator.

Comment: Apache
PHP5FastCGI

At least am 99.9% sure.

Comment: I went to the site and did not receive this error. When you see it does it appear on the frontend, admin backend, or both? Also try clearing your browser cookies/sessions.

Answer (score 0):

That error is usually from extra white space or garbage characters before the opening `<?php` of a file, or from a file being saved at UTF-8 with BOM rather than without BOM (Byte Order Mark). Did you edit any files? It could also be simply a transient error from the automatic upgrade and those problematic files were deleted.

Answer (score 0):

We've just run into this today and the sys-admin guys had to change permissions of that directory. Which could be done with chmod. Not sure that this is the issue, but worked in our scenario.

If you're just wanting to suppress the error, there should be a setting in the wp-config.php file that you can change to suppress WP errors

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Which more info can be found at http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Otherwise, if you're just wanting to suppress general php errors, the answer from this post should work too.

[Best way to suppress php errors on production servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332178/best-way-to-suppress-php-errors-on-production-servers)