# PHP socket closing forcibly by client

Tags: c#, php, sockets, php-socket

I created a PHP's socket server. I connected to it using telnet or putty and everything works just well, until I tried to connect to in a .Net application, each time I execute the app it closes the server, here's my C# code, just the two lines:

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient cli = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("192.168.0.200", 10000);
cli.Close();
```

When I run the app the PHP socket server is closed with this error:

```
Warning: socket_read(): unable to read from socket [0]: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I tried commenting out the `Cli.close()` line, and sure enough the socket stayed open until the C# app is closed, then it will close with the same error message above.

So what is causing the problem?, client should not be able to close the socket this way.

Thank you

Comment: Can you give a php code responsible for socket reading?

Comment: It is exactly the same as the one in the manual's example http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Comment: What is your problem? If the client closes the connection, what do you expect? If you connect with telnet/putty, and you KILL the connection by closing telnet/putty with taskmanager (so without typing `quit` or `shutdown` in telnet/putty) , do you get different behaviour ?

Comment: @nl-x in the .Net app, when the client closes the connection, it does not just disconnect the client's connection, it closes the connection server as well, while when using putty or Microsoft's telnet, quitting or even closing client application forcibly does not do the same, the socket stays open waiting for future clients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code at http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php I do not see any problems with it. This code exists the script when socket is closed:

```
if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
        echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
        break 2;
    }
```

What I can suggest is to modify the code as follow:

```
if (false === ($buf = @socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
        echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
```

Adding '@' will prevent warning to appear. Changing `break 2;` to `break;` will make server not to exit but to keep waiting for a next connection.

If this doesn't work than you can wrap the whole script to another `do { } while()` loop so that every time the socket read fails php do `socket_create()` again.

Comment: This solution works but I feel like it is not the way to do it, I am still getting the error message (if I do not suppress it with @) which I believe should not be the case, but I could send quit when the app is closed in the .Net app to solve this issue, thank you

Comment: Warning is the normal behaviour for `socket_read` while not the best one.  On the production you can disable warnings by doing something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332178/best-way-to-suppress-php-errors-on-production-servers . Good luck.

Comment: the thing is the break 2, break 2 applies to breaks. which closes the if and the do while